# $g_2(z)=g_1(z)+O(z^n)$ implies $1/g_2(z)=1/g_1(z)+O(z^n)$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let $f_2,g_2:B_r(0) \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be two holomorphic functions such that $f_2(z)=f_1(z)+O(z^n)$ and $g_2(z)=g_1(z)+O(z^n)$, here $O(z^n)$ denotes a power series of the form $\sum_{k=n} a_k z^k$, that is, without terms of order less than $z^n$. Once said that, I want to prove that if $g_2(z) \neq 0 $ for all $z \in B_r(z_0)$ then
$$
\frac{f_2(z)}{g_2(z)}=\frac{f_1(z)}{g_1(z)}+O(z^n)
$$

My attempt was as follows: without loss of generality we can write $g_2(z)=g_1(z)-O(z^n)$ which entails that
$$
\frac{f_2(z)}{g_2(z)}=\frac{f_1(z)+O(z^n)}{g_1(z)-O(z^n)}=\frac{f_1(z)+O(z^n)}{g_1(z)} \frac{1}{1-\frac{O(z^n)}{g_1(z)}}
$$
Next, I tried to write
$$
\frac{1}{1-\frac{O(z^n)}{g_1(z)}}=\left( 1+ \frac{O(z^n)}{g_1(z)}+ \frac{O(z^n)^2}{g_1(z)^2}+\cdots  \right)
$$
However, as you can see, there is several issues with this approach. First, the above series only converges when $\vert O(z^n) \vert < \vert g_1(z) \vert$ (hypothesis that by the way I don't have). Second, even if that series converges we cannot ensure that $\frac{O(z^n)}{g_1(z)}=O(z^n)$ (as far as I know).

Any help in order to prove this statement?

In advance thank you.

Comment: @MartinR you're right, I have already edited the post. Thanks for noticing and for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the difference as
$$
\frac{f_2(z)}{g_2(z)}-\frac{f_1(z)}{g_1(z)} = \frac{f_2(z)g_1(z)-f_1(z)g_2(z)}{g_1(z)g_2(z)}\\=
\frac{f_2(z)(g_1(z)-g_2(z))+(f_2(z)-f_1(z))g_2(z)}{g_1(z)g_2(z)} \\
= \frac{f_2(z)}{g_1(z)g_2(z)} (g_1(z)-g_2(z)) + (f_2(z)-f_1(z))\frac{1}{g_1(z)}
$$
and conclude that this is $O(z^n)$.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your help! Just to make sure I'm understanding correctly: $g_1-g_2=O(z^n)$ and also $f_2-f_1=O(z^n)$ therefore $f_2/g_2-f_1/g_1=O(z^n)(\frac{f_2+g_2}{g_1g_2})$ but $f_2+g_2=O(z^n)$ and $g_1g_2=O(z^n)$ and thus $\frac{f_2+g_2}{g_1g_2}=O(1)$ which implies that $f_2/g_2-f_1/g_1=O(z^n)$, is that right?

Comment: @ferolimen: $\frac{f_2(z)}{g_1(z)g_2(z)} (g_1(z)-g_2(z)) = O(z_n)$ and $(f_2(z)-f_1(z))\frac{1}{g_1(z)} = O(z^n)$. And the sum of two $O(z^n)$ functions is again $O(z^n)$.

Comment: Maybe this question is a little bit evident but why $\frac{f_2(z)}{g_1(z)g_2(z)}(g_1(z)-g_2(z))=O(z^n)$? It's not clear at all for me. It follow from the hypothesis  that $g1(z)-g_2(z)=O(z^n)$ but what about the other term?

Comment: @SCarlsen: $g_1(z)-g_2(z)$ has a power series starting with $z^n$ terms. If you multiply that with any other power series then the product still starts with $z^n$ terms. Or: If $g_1(z)-g_2(z) = z^n \phi(z)$ with $\phi$ holomorphic in $B_r(0)$ then $\frac{f_2(z)}{g_1(z)g_2(z)}(g_1(z)-g_2(z))=z^n \psi(z)$ with $\psi$ holomorphic in $B_r(0)$.

Comment: @MartinR of course! Thank you very much for the explanation :D!